# ireport/jasperreport forecolor not applied for excel report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with a "header" style:

```
<style name="header" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#15315B" vAlign="Middle" fontName="Arial" fontSize="10" isBold="true"/>
```

It is correctly displayed when I create a PDF report (`JRPdfExporter`), but when I create a XLSX report (`JRXlsxExporter`), the text stay in black and not in bold instead of white and bold...

I use jasperreport 5.6.

Example of text using the style:

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement style="header" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="b5ee91c1-614a-40f8-96d3-2f626544e7c1"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
    <text><![CDATA[Field]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated jasperreport to version 6.0.3 and it now works...